# Wildcard 'A' record overriding CNAME record

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, wildcard, a-record

I have a Wildcard * A record for self-registration of subdomains by users on our web app.  All works fine.

I now need to set up an alias for support.mydomain.com to point to mydomain.freshdesk.com.  I created a CNAME record as per instructions however it appears my Wildcard A record is overriding the CNAME entry.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?  I need the wildcard so creating an A record for each user subdomain is not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You or your Recursive DNS server probably have the result cached. Clear the cache and try again; or use a resolver like `dig` or `nslookup` pointed directly at your authoritative server.

Comment: please show your actual DNS records - as described this shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 11):

The more specific DNS record overrides the wildcard. So your CNAME should override your wildcard A. What this might be is that you still have the domain name cached to the a record. Use the dig command:

```
dig @yourdnsserver mydomain.freshdesk.com
```

Normally it should return the CNAME.